# how to pause the image when i click stop button

Tags: android, android-animation

i have 2 buttons(start&stop) and 1 image when i click start button image will move from top to bottom and bottom to top, this is fine but the problem when i click stop button image is gone but i wont that.my requirement is image has to pause on the screen until i click start button. i am waiting for u r response

please help me and once execute my code u can understand clearly

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
RelativeLayout rl_footer;
ImageView iv_header;
boolean isBottom = true;
Button btn1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    rl_footer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_footer);
    iv_header = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_up_arrow);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button buttonstop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    buttonstop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            rl_footer.clearAnimation();
            rl_footer.removeAllViews();
        }
    });
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            iv_header.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
            iv_header.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0);
            // rl_footer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.download);
            // if (isBottom) {
            SlideToAbove();
            // isBottom = false;

            // } else {
            // iv_header.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
            // iv_header.setPadding(0, 0, 0,50);
            // rl_footer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.download);
            // SlideToDown();
            // isBottom = true;
            // }

        }
    });
}

public void SlideToAbove() {
    Animation slide = null;
    slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -5.0f);

    slide.setDuration(400);
    slide.setFillAfter(true);
    slide.setFillEnabled(true);
    rl_footer.startAnimation(slide);

    slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
```

//              rl_footer.clearAnimation();

```
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    rl_footer.getWidth(), rl_footer.getHeight());
            // lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            rl_footer.setLayoutParams(lp);
            iv_header.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
            iv_header.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 50);
            SlideToDown();
        }

    });

}

public void SlideToDown() {
    Animation slide = null;
    slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 5.2f);

    slide.setDuration(400);
    slide.setFillAfter(true);
    slide.setFillEnabled(true);
    rl_footer.startAnimation(slide);

    slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
```

//              rl_footer.clearAnimation();

```
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    rl_footer.getWidth(), rl_footer.getHeight());
            lp.setMargins(0, rl_footer.getWidth(), 0, 0);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            rl_footer.setLayoutParams(lp);
            iv_header.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
            iv_header.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0);
            SlideToAbove();

        }

    });

}

}
```

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rl_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_up_arrow"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rl_footer"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="start" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="84dp"
    android:text="stop" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you re-write the top paragraph. I don't understand your question.

Comment: thank for u r reply friend.i have 2 buttons(start&stop) and 1 image when i click start button image will move from top to bottom and bottom to top, this is fine but the problem when i click stop button image is gone but i wont that.but my requirement is image  has to pause on the screen until i click start button. i am waiting for u r response

Answer (score 0):

```
clearAnimation()
```

*Cancels any animations for this view.*

```
removeAllViews()
```

*Call this method to remove all child views from the ViewGroup.*

Try removing this line:

> rl_footer.removeAllViews();

Comment: thanku for u r response friend,please check my main activity i am using same methods in my buttonStop event listener but it is not working,if u dont mind once execute my code u will get what the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
 rl_footer.removeAllViews();
```

"Call this method to remove all child views from the ViewGroup".
Comment this and the image shouldn't disappear.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes image is not disappear but it is not stay on the screen image moves continuously even i am click the stop button

Comment: try rl..setAnimation(null);

Comment: only this method or adding existing method please clarify

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, don't call removeAllViews.

If you call clearAnimation, the View will go back to its original position.
If you don't call clearAnimation, the View will continue to animate.

What you need to do is to calculate the amount of time into the current animation cycle, then create a new Animation with a 0 duration, fillEnabled, fillBefore and fillAfter set to true and for the amount of translation to be equal to the amount that the current animation would have been offsetting the View.

Comment: thanku for ur response friend , i am trying but it is not working , will you please edit the code as u said  above and if u dont mind will u execute my code.